# How to change url like .php?name=neco to url /neco in .htaccess?

Tags: php, .htaccess, url, server

Ive been trying this commands, but with no luck :

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^product/(.*+) product.php?name=$1
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your `mod_rewrite` rules are inside an `IfModule`:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    #...
</IfModule>
```

The rule you have will reroute `example.com/product/foo` to `example.com/product.php?name=foo`.

If you want to route `example.com/foo` to `example.com/bar.php?name=foo` you can do this:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteBase /
    RewriteRule ^([^/]*)$ /bar.php?name=$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 0):

so it will looks like this?

```
    Options +FollowSymLinks
    RewriteEngine on
    <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
        RewriteBase /
        RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9]+)$ product.php?name=$1 [L]
    </IfModule>
```

Ive been trying lot of Rewrite Rules, but nothin happens the script and .htaccess are in same directory of course